# AWS cloudfront route root to EC2 route anything else to S3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

We have an angular app living in `S3` we would like our domain to serve when there is anything after the `/` but a flat html page and basic assets to be served from an `EC2` when the root of the domain is accessed.

So far we have not gotten anything to work and we're really hoping we can make something work.

So far in cloudfront we have try to make the default route to an `EC2` origin and `/*` and event `/` route to an `S3` origin but nothing seems to be working.

How can we get our domatin `example.com` serve our `EC2` files but anything other than the root, ie. `example.com/one, example.com/two, etc.` route to the `S3` single page app

Answer (score 0):

> So far in cloudfront we have try to make the default route to an EC2 origin and /* and event / route to an S3 origin but nothing seems to be working.

If I understand what you're trying to do, that's sort of backwards.  `*` matches everything, including nothing, and including more slashes.

Create a new cache behavior matching the path `/` and pointing to EC2 origin.  This catches the main page.

Create a new cache behavior matching the path `/*/*` pointing to the EC2 origin.  This catches anything in a folder, e.g. `/pics/cats.jpg` and `/pics/cats/funny.jpg` and `/pics/cats/hilarious/lol.jpg`.

If there are any files (other than the main page) in the root of the web server in EC2, create a new cache behavior matching the path `/*.*` pointing to the EC2 origin.  This catches files in the root directory, e.g. `/cat.jpg`.

Point the default cache behavior to S3.  Everything already matched by the two or three other behaviors goes to EC2, and what's left over goes to the bucket, which would be `/` followed by any characters *excluding* another `/` or `.`, which would have been captured by one of the behaviors routing to EC2.

Comment: We tried this and it doesn't seem to be working. No matter what I type after the main slash it all goes to the balancer.

Comment: Did you set S3 as the origin of the default behavior and then the additional paths to EC2?  Did you do a cache invalidation request after making the changes, and wait for the distribution to transition back to "Deployed" before testing?  Also, let's clarify... you want `/` to go to EC2, `/something-here` to S3, and `/something/like/this` to EC2?

Comment: I can do it all again and make sure all the steps are complete and test again but even after several hours it still didn't take. Ideally anything other than `/` should go to the `S3` but `/` should be the `EC2`